# How to remove XML parent node based on child conditions PHP

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath

Hi I am trying to clean up xml file out of positions I dont need. Here is my code so far:

```
<?php
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    $doc->load('merg.xml');

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    $products = $xpath->query('//offer/products/*');

    printf('There is %d products<br /><br />', $products->length);

    function findStopPointByName($xml, $query) {
      $upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZĄŻŚĆŹĆÓŁ";
      $lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzążśćźńół";
      $arg_query    = "translate('$query', '$upper', '$lower')";

      return $xml->query("//offer/products/product/description/name[contains(text(),$arg_query)]");
    }
    foreach(findStopPointByName($xpath,'Skór') as $node)
    {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }

    $doc->save('merg_fixed.xml');
?>
```

Structure of XML:

```
<offer>
 <products>
  <product>
   <description>
    <name>Name of the product</name>
     ...
    </name>
     ...
   </description>
  </product>
 </products>
</offer>
```

I am trying to remove all PRODUCT where its NAME contains 'Skór' in any case (Skór, skór, SKÓR - is enough). Funcion findStopPointByName returns DOMNodeList of correct length, but nothing is removed from actual XML file, please help.

Comment: Try using this XPath query instead : `//offer/products/product[description/name[contains(.,translate('$query', '$upper', '$lower'))]]`

Comment: It produces exactly same result. Do I try to remove nodes in a correct way? 

Maybe it will be simpler to write 3 querries for there type of case - Skór, skór, SKÓR ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can directly find node product with the condition

Second, to make search case insensitive, you can translate node text in any case but should use pattern in the same case. As the result, your code may be so

```
 function findStopPointByName($xml, $query) {
  $upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZĄŻŚĆŹĆÓŁ";
  $lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzążśćźńół";
  $arg_query    = "translate(text(), '$upper', '$lower')";
  $q = "//product[description/name[contains($arg_query, '$query')]]" ."\n";
  return $xml->query($q);
}

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load('merg.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach(findStopPointByName($xpath,'skór') as $node)
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);

echo $doc->saveXML();
```

[**Demo on eval.in**](https://eval.in/411678)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I have tried it and it is not working on my file maybe the reason is different construction of `<name>` node `<description><name xml:lang="pol"><![CDATA[Skórzane BUTY CZARNE z KLAMRĄ Moda i STYL]]></name>`

Comment: I am sorry I have made a small typo when converting your answer to my code. It works like a charm. Thank you!